# Applescript to check App Store

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-yosemite

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

It's pretty simple, but i am a complete noobie to this, so am having some trouble.

Is it possible to have an applescript that will check the mac app store for updates, and if there are, output the number of updates to someplace?

A good example of this is (if you are aware of it) the geeklets that check for unread mail, and then outputs it to the desktop.

EDIT:
I downloaded a geeklet for the unread mail (as referenced above), and using that as a starting point, I tried to write my own script.

```
set run_bool to 1

tell application "System Events"
    set run_bool to count (every process whose name is "App Store")
end tell


if run_bool is 1 then

    tell application "App Store"

        set update_count to 0
        set output_string to ""

        repeat with upd in Apps in Updates
            if upd's download is not true then
                set update_count to update_count + 1
            end if
        end repeat

        if update_count is 0 then
            set output_string to "zero"

        else if update_count is 1 then
            set output_string to "one"

        else
            set output_string to "two"
        end if
    end tell

else
    set output_string to "not running"
end if

return output_string
```

now this is not my final code, but simply to check to see if it will work and what the output would be.

On compilation I get an error saying

> error "The variable Updates is not defined." number -2753 from "Updates"

as well as

> **Syntax Error**
>   Expected end of line but found unknown token

Also, when I stopped compilation, this appeared below the last line in my code

> tell application "GeekTool Helper"
>     activate
>     «event ascrgsdf»

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you don't just click the  menu?  The number of updates is shown next to the "App Store..." menu item, assuming the "Automatically check for updates" option is checked in System Preferences' App Store tab.

Comment: @foo I am aware of this, and I also have app store on my dock, which shows the update count in the little red circle. However, I'm streamlining my desktop to be as minimal as possible. Having it automatically shown on my desktop via a geeklet will allow me to be notified every time there is an update to be done, and I don't have to periodically check the App Store manually.

Comment: Your script can't work because App Store.app is not actually AppleScriptable. It shows a dictionary in Script Editor, but that's only the default Cocoa Scripting terminology you see when the `NSAppleScriptEnabled` flag is set in the app's `Info.plist` file. It doesn't actually do anything useful unless the developers have provided their own app-specific terms and Objective-C code to wire it all up, which they haven't. (App Store's not the only Apple app to do this "Fake AppleScriptability" either, which is very annoying/confusing/insulting, but then most Apple devs want AS to DIAF anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

@foo is pretty right on with his idea. This code only requires one line. In the second line, I used `display notification`, but you substitute it with you preferred method to pass on the value.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (first application process whose ¬
frontmost is true) to set returnValue to title of ((first menu item whose title ¬
begins with "App Store") of menu "Apple" of menu bar 1)
display notification returnValue
```

Result:

```
"App Store…, 1 update"
```

[image: notification]

`menu bar items` are accessible everywhere (e.g. windowed/numeral desktop mode, fullscreen mode, dock hidden/disabled).

Make sure **accessibility** is enabled for Script Editor, or whichever app you use to invoke the script, to gain access to the UI.

There is just one weird thing: if I had used `begins with "App Store..."` instead of `begins with "App Store"`, the code would be a dud. I don't know why - it might has to do with escaped characters and the `...`. Anyone who knows please enlighten me with a comment.

As for your code, I can tell from **AppleScript Dictionary** that `Updates` is not a property of `App Store.app`. Nor is any other categories in the UI. To get to the Dictionary, open Script Editor and press CMD+SHIFT+O

In addition, if you want to use `return` statement, you need an **explicit handler**. In other words, you need to wrap the code between `on run` and `end run`.

Comment: thank you so much for this, i appreciate it. it seems i did not understand what @foo was talking about, but your post cleared it up. i am unable to test this out right now, but when i do (and it works then hopefully), i will be upvoting you. cheers.

Comment: Actually I was just saying to click on the Apple menu to view the most recent update count there, but yeah, you could use GUI Scripting to extract that data for use elsewhere. GUI Scripting's painful, fragile, and plain old evil, but it's the only practical option when dealing with non-scriptable apps like App Store. (If you really care, you could file a [feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com) to make App Store scriptable - but don't hold your breath for a result as Apple really doesn't give a crap about AppleScript any more.)

Comment: @foo Feature request? LOL, I just hope it's more usable. UI takes ages to respond. I have 2 apps forever reside under "Check for Unfinished Downloads...". Xcode get stalled so many times doing its 2 Gig update, that I simply dl the `.dmg` from developer page, when I get to it, that is Hence, the `1 update` right now in my app store.